# How to display a local json file with material-table

Tags: reactjs, json, material-table

I am a beginner in React and material-table.
I want to read a json file that has about 1000 objects like the following and output it to a table.

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3"
}
```

I was able to achieve this with the following code, but the data retrieval is slow, so I want to switch to a local json file.

```
    useEffect(() => {   fetch("example.com/api")
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(resp => {
                setData(resp)
            })
    }, [])
```

The version of react is 17.0.2 and material-table/core is 4.3.18.
I am also using typescript.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. import data from '../data.json'. and then import it with data={data} to display the data. Thanks.